# MySQL Foreign-keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've attempted to create foreign keys in my Movie_Copies table which references the primary keys in the tables Movie_Details and Customer_Details but it doesn't seem to work for me and the syntax error that appears seems to be with the indexing.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Movie_Renting`.`Movie_Details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Movie_Renting`.`Movie_Details` (
  `Movie_ID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_Title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `Release_Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Run_Time` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Genre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Rating` INT NOT NULL,
  `Number_of_Copies` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Movie_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Movie_Renting`.`Customer_Details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Movie_Renting`.`Customer_Details` (
  `Customer_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Name` VARCHAR(800) NOT NULL,
  `Address_Line_One` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address_Line_Two` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Town` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `Post_Code` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `Contact_Number` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  `Email_Address` VARCHAR(345) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Movie_Renting`.`Movie_Copies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Movie_Renting`.`Movie_Copies` (
  `Copy_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Movie_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Platform` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Rent_Out` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Duration_Weeks` INT NOT NULL,
  `Return_Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Details_Customer_ID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Copy_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Movie_Copies_Movie_Details_idx` (`Movie_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Movie_Copies_Customer_Details1_idx` (`Customer_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Movie_Copies_Movie_Details`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Movie_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Movie_Renting`.`Movie_Details` (`Movie_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Movie_Copies_Customer_Details1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Movie_Renting`.`Customer_Details` (`Customer_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The `VISIBLE` keyword isn't available unless you are running MySQL 8.0 or later. You can safely remove it if you are running MySQL < 8.0

Comment: I have just tried that but i get the error message; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fk_Movie_Copies_Movie_Details_idx' ('Movie_ID' ASC),
  INDEX 'fk_Movie_Copies_C' at line 10

Comment: I cut and pasted your code (minus the `VISIBLE`) into my MySQL 5.6 server and it works perfectly.

Comment: I notice the string lengths of the columns in the `Movie_Copies` table aren't the same as the corresponding columns in the `Customer_Details` and `Movie_Details` tables. I've known MySQL to get a bit stroppy about that sort of thing